# How to listen to click action on AppCompat's Toolbar logo/text and back navigation item separately?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

[image]

I am totally lost on this. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Aren't you inflating that custom view on action bar?

Comment: this is not custom view

Comment: Then how have you added two images i.e back arrow and square

Comment: using setNavigationIcon() and setLogo() on toolbar

Comment: have you tried toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override  public void onClick(View v) { }});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use toolbar:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:background="@color/light_blue"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/action_home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/touch_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:padding="@dimen/small">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/home_icon"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_square_icon"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home_icon"
                android:text="My App"
                android:textColor="@color/white_color"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/small"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and in your code:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    toolbar.findViewById(R.id.action_home).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             // custom implementation
            }
        });
```

and implement OnClick()

Comment: with some editing to your code I was able to come to a solution. Thanks